# VLC for Android TV keeps freezing with 4K videos

Tags: android-tv, vlc

My VLC (version 3.5.1) for Android TV (Sony tv with Android TV OS 10) keeps freezing after 10-15 min of 4K video from lan computer over wifi. I have no trouble with 1080p videos. I tried a bunch of config tweaks (like increasing buffer time, changing smb settings) to no avail. I’ll usually need to restart the app when this happens. I just tried with another app and didn’t get any problem. I'm not having any problem with VLC for PC.

I tried enabling debug logs and now the log section is completely grayed out and I can't interact with it at all :(

Does anyone else experience this? Any help much appreciated!

Comment: If you restart the app and continue watching does it again work for 10-15 minutes or is the time now shorter?

Comment: Mmm good question. Just tested, it’s not consistent. Just watched about 1 hour of 4K with no problem. And I’ve seen sometimes what you described, where starting the video again after a problem would freeze after just a few minutes.

Comment: Then a thermal problem could be the cause. May be the CPU overheats and throttles itself. because of the reduced CPU speed the video stops and the whole app hangs.

Comment: mmm are there VLC settings I could set to reduce CPU usage?

Comment: Not sure about VLC, I would recommend MXPlayer as it display if a video is decoded in software or partially/fully in hardware. Hardware decoding is very efficient and should not overheat your CPU/GPU, but pure software decoding could be a problem.